# Are wearing clothes that differ from the congregation you are currently praying with a violation of “Lo Titgodedu”?

Tags: halacha

Suppose someone is wearing Chassidic Levush (non-Chabad) in a litvish shul, is this transgressing “Lo Titgodedu”?

Comment: Most shuls don't have a "dress code". So, I think this would be based on the rules and minhag of the shul. It sounds no worse than those wearing jeans and a T-shirt on Shabbat. I'm not suggesting that it's respectful, but I don't think it violates this mitzvah.

Comment: Isn't lo sisgodidu by batei dinin?

Comment: @sam not sure if clothing customs are included

Comment: IIRC, anything backed by a community (and its Beis Din) is not considered Lo Titgodedu. So, for example, in Jerusalem, everyone represents a community, including those who represent the community of those who are not represented by any other community. Therefore everyone is allowed to follow his own traditions.